# How to add "Align Center Y to" constraint?

Tags: xcode, constraints

In InterfaceBuilder, is there a way to add an

> Align Center Y to

constraint? I can't find this type of constraint anywhere and I'm not sure how to create it by control + drag.

Comment: You mean align top or bottom of a `UIView` to your `UIViewController`'s view center Y?

Comment: In interface builder I believe it is called "vertical center" so it would be something like "align veritcal centers"

Comment: @Fogmeister: That's it. thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Align center Y to` = Center Vertically
> Align center X to = Center Horizontally.

Press control on your element, hold it and link it to an other element, select Center ....

[image]